# How to replace word/s between a xml tag

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use regex in C# to search for a specific word in a word document xml file (in this below example search for 'des') to be replaced with the desired word.

```
<w:r>
    <w:t>Some example des test desmond end of sentence</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">Some test sentence des and desmond end of testing</w:t>
</w:r>
```

I need the regex to only look for the words between the starting tags => "<w:t>" or "<w:t xml:space="preserve">" and the end tags => "</w:t>

While differentiating the difference between "des" and "desmond"

After testing, these are the closest regex I came up with that kind of works.

1. (<w:t[^>]* >)(.* )\bdes\b(.* )(</w:t>)
2. (?<=(<w:t[^>]* >))(.* )\bdes\b(.* )(?=(</w:t>))

First one seems to search for the whole tag <w:t>blah blah</w:t> and replace that whole search group to a replacement word,  while the second one throws an error saying that a look-behind cannot be a non-fixed width.

What regex can match the specific word/s only between the "<w:t>" tags?

Comment: Regex doesn't work well with XML. Why don't you use an XML parser to find the specific string you want, and then just do a simple replace of the text value? This way you don't need worry about your regex handling XML.

Comment: Consider using a parser instead of a regex. C# does support a quantifier in the lookbehind, see the a [.NET regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3cw%3at%5b%5e%3e%5d*%3e%29%29%28.*%3f%29%5cbdes%5cb%28.*%3f%29%28%3f%3d%28%3c%5c%2fw%3at%3e%29%29&i=%3cw%3ar%3e%0d%0a++++%3cw%3at%3eSome+example+des+test+desmond+end+of+sentence%3c%2fw%3at%3e%0d%0a%3c%2fw%3ar%3e%0d%0a%3cw%3ar%3e%0d%0a++++%3cw%3at+xml%3aspace%3d%22preserve%22%3eSome+test+sentence+des+and+desmond+end+of+testing%3c%2fw%3at%3e%0d%0a%3c%2fw%3ar%3e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `(<w:t[^>]* >)(.* )\bdes\b(.* )(</w:t>)`

I think you could use a capturing group for word which you want to replace. You coud try following regex.

```
(<w:t[^>]*>.*?)\b(des)\b(.*?</w:t>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ea7fI0/1)

I also tried to test on C#.

```
    string item = "<w:r>"
                    +"    <w:t>Some example des test desmond end of sentence</w:t>"
                    +"</w:r>"
                    +"<w:r>"
                    +"    <w:t xml:space=\"preserve\">Some test sentence des and desmond end of testing</w:t>"
                    +"</w:r>";
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    
    string result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(item,@"(<w:t[^>]*>.*?)\b(des)\b(.*?</w:t>)", "$1new value$3");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/W0I1Um